# How can I make a ComboBox in a DataGrid row unique?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

Environment for the following question:
C#, WPF, XAML

How can I achieve to setup a table/a DataGrid with an undefined number of rows having a Combobox in an arbitrary column (number of columns is undefined as well)? (The other row's cells will be filled with the properties of the underyling object/entity.) The ComboBoxes shall all have the same items but the selected item shall be assigned to the underlying object of the row (of course). Hence, I think the ComboBox of each row must have a unique identifier.
The selected item shall be stored in a property of the underlying object/entity.

By the way: 
The ComboBox shall be filled with items of a collection (List) that is not part of the row's underlying object/entity.

What would be the best way using WPF / XAML?

UPDATE (2018-12-14):

```
    <Window x:Class="ConfigTool.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ConfigTool"
        xmlns:lb="clr-namespace:ConfigTool.DataBinding"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="xxx" Height="650" Width="1200" Closing="CloseWindow">

    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="TagsCollectionViewSource" CollectionViewType="ListCollectionView"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="NotificationsCollectionViewSource" CollectionViewType="ListCollectionView"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="TagNamesCollectionViewSource" CollectionViewType="ListCollectionView"/>

        <lb:StringListConverter x:Key="StringListConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Margin="10,10,10,10">
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Tags">
                <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <DataGrid x:Name="tagsGrid" DataContext="{StaticResource TagsCollectionViewSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                              AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="True" IsReadOnly="False" 
                              SelectionMode="Single" BorderBrush="Magenta" BorderThickness="3">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="TagName" Header="Tag name" Binding="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=TagName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Cycle" Binding="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=Cycle}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Source" Binding="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=Source}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="editTagColumn" Header="Edit">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <WrapPanel>
                                            <Button x:Name="btnTagDelete" Click="BtnTagDelete_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Height="15" Width="15" Margin="2">
                                                <Button.Content>
                                                    <Image Source="Resources/delete.png"></Image>
                                                </Button.Content>
                                            </Button>
                                        </WrapPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Notifications">
                <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <DataGrid x:Name="notificationsGrid" DataContext="{StaticResource NotificationsCollectionViewSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                              AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="True" IsReadOnly="False" 
                              SelectionMode="Single" BorderBrush="Magenta" BorderThickness="3">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <!--<DataGridTextColumn Header="Tag name" Binding="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=TagName}"></DataGridTextColumn>-->
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="tagNameColumn" Header="Tag name">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <!--<ItemContainerTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel>-->
                                            <!--DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource TagNamesCollectionViewSource}}">-->
                                            <!--<ComboBox Width="200" DataContext="{StaticResource TagNamesCollectionViewSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding TagNames, Converter={StaticResource StringListConverter}}">-->
                                        <ComboBox Name="notificationTagName" Width="200" DataContext="{StaticResource TagNamesCollectionViewSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TagNamesCollectionViewSource}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:MainWindow}}" 
                                                  SelectionChanged="notificationTagName_SelectionChanged" />
                                            <!--<ComboBox Width="200" DataContext="{StaticResource TagNamesCollectionViewSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource StringListConverter}}" />-->
                                            <!--<ComboBox Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Window2, Path=DataContext.TagNames, Converter={StaticResource StringListConverter}}" />-->
                                            <!--<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="256,260,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" x:Name="DataList" ItemsSource="{Binding DetailParams, Converter={StaticResource StringListConverter}}"/>-->
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                    <!--</StackPanel>
                                    </ItemContainerTemplate>-->
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="IsActive" Binding="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsActive}"></DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=Type}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Limit" Binding="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=Limit}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="DetailTemplate" Binding="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=DetailTemplate}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <!--<DataGridTextColumn Header="DetailParams" Binding="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=DetailParams, Converter={StaticResource StringListConverter}}"></DataGridTextColumn>-->
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="detailsParamColumn" Header="Edit">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <ItemContainerTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel> <!--DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource TagNamesCollectionViewSource}}">-->
                                            <!--<ComboBox Width="200" DataContext="{StaticResource TagNamesCollectionViewSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding TagNames, Converter={StaticResource StringListConverter}}">-->
                                            <ComboBox Width="200" DataContext="{StaticResource TagNamesCollectionViewSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
                                            <!--<ComboBox Width="200" DataContext="{StaticResource TagNamesCollectionViewSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource StringListConverter}}" />-->
                                            <!--<ComboBox Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Window2, Path=DataContext.TagNames, Converter={StaticResource StringListConverter}}" />-->
                                            <!--<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="256,260,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" x:Name="DataList" ItemsSource="{Binding DetailParams, Converter={StaticResource StringListConverter}}"/>-->
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </ItemContainerTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="CauseProbability" Binding="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=CauseProbability, Converter={StaticResource StringListConverter}}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="editNotificationsColumn" Header="Edit">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <WrapPanel>
                                            <Button x:Name="btnNotificationDelete" Click="BtnNotificationDelete_Click" Height="15" Width="15" Margin="2">
                                                <Image Source="Resources/delete.png"></Image>
                                            </Button>
                                        </WrapPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: You can do that with an ItemsControl. you can do everything with an ItemsControl.

Comment: With a comboboxcolumn you only get an actual combobox in the row you're editing. Hence the combo you get is always going to be unique. When  you edit and choose an entry out that combo then it only sets that value to the row you edit.  I don't follow why you specifically stress uniqueness. Please explain further.

Comment: I am new to C#, XAM, WPF an dI try to present a DataGrid with rows for each CSV line. One CSV item shall be displayed as a ComboBox getting its items from somewhere else but the selected item shall be rewritten in the CSV which is represented by a class for each line. When I change a rows item in a ComboBox it changes the item in ALL rows. ...see updated question.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you are using the same collection for the Combo-Box in each row.
The ItemsSource for the Combo-Box should be a collection and it should be a member/property of class that set as DataContext for the DataGrid.

**Or**

Bind the SelectedItem property of Combo-Box to a member of your class.
See https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/combobox-in-datagrid-in-wpf/